# Drupal 7 - show logged in user full name and email id

Tags: drupal-7

I know that I can fetch the logged in user's name as

```html
<?php
global $user;
print $user->name;
?>
```

However, I want to know how to show logged in user's full name (first and last name) and email id. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use print_r($user) to look at the $user object. But i dont think global $user includes profile fields, so you might have to load the user object again like so:

```
global $user;
$account = user_load($user->uid);
print_r($account);
```

And the email field is usually:

```
$user->mail;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still using drupal 7. you can get the user profile like this:

```
global $user;

$account = user_load($user->uid);

$user_email = $account->field_profile_email[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["email"];

$user_first_name = $account->field_first_names[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["value"];

$user_last_name = $account->field_surname[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]["value"];

$user_full_name = "$user_first_name $user_last_name";
```